# Form watch with debounce fires multiple ng-submit events when hitting enter

Tags: angularjs

I need to watch a form input for changes and fire a search. The search also contains a number of filters for searching(not shown in plnkr). I'm watching the form object to accomplish this. The input is debounced as to not make repeated requests. The problem I have is that when a user types a search value and hits enter the `submit()` function fires twice, One from the watch and one from the enter key ng-submit. How would I refactor this? I need the user to be able to input text in the search field and have the search trigger after the debounce interval, but if they input text and hit enter it should ignore the watch. I can think of may different ways to try to fix this, but was hoping I could get a preferred solution from one of you :) Thanks!

See this: https://plnkr.co/edit/LS5cQzs9X4NGI745po7C?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="submitExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'hello';
      $scope.$watch('text', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue != oldValue) {
          $scope.submit();
        }
      });
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
          $scope.list.push(this.text);
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want the form submit and the input text model change call the same function? It's doing exactly what you coded it to do.

Comment: with your code always will be triggered twice because, the watch dowsnt know y enter was pressed. what is the functionality you want for your form?. may be can helping construct the logic for the form.

Comment: Use the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead of $watch.

Comment: @georgeawg that doesnt solve the problem when he press enter fire both submit

Comment: i think is better to know wich functionlity want to do with the form.

Comment: The reason for the watch is that the search is a part of a larger interface with filters (~20 checkboxes). I'm doing a $watch on the form data.